# SQL create new table and insert data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the difference of GPA among Semesters.

```
ID 1 Semester Fall   GPA: 3.0
ID 1 Semester Spring GPA: 3.5
ID 2 Semester Fall   GPA: 3.0
ID 3 Semester Fall   GPA: 3.0
ID 3 Semester Spring GPA: 3.2
```

Because ID 2 does not have spring GPA, i can not compared between two semesters.
So, how should i write to find out the difference GPA for ID 1 and ID 3 ?

```
ID 1 : .5
ID 3 : .2
```

Comment: please share your efforts !

Answer (score 3):

Self join:

```
select a.id, 
    b.gpa - a.gpa as diff
from your_table a
join your_table b on a.id = b.id
where a.semester = 'Fall'
and b.semester = 'Spring';
```